# Coding style - how do I format a long if condition to make it readable

Tags: php, coding-style

I have a long if condition as follows. There are two conditions that both have to not be met, for the statement to evaluate. I did have it as a one liner with a lot of && and ! but it became unreadable. I have tried splitting it into an `if elsif else`, which is more readable but doesn't read well, as the first `if elsif` blocks have no code in them.

What would be the best practice to tidy this code block?

```
if ($instructionObject->instruction=='nesting_grammar' && $instructionObject->match=='>'){ //if instruction is a '>' child indicator
   //don't change the child depth
}else if ($instructionObject->instruction=='selector' && is_object($this->instructions[$key+1]) && $this->instructions[$key+1]->instruction == 'nesting_grammar' && $this->instructions[$key+1]->match == '>'){ //if instruction is a selector followed by a '>'
   //don't change the child depth
}else{
   $insertOffset += $childDepth;
   unset($childDepth);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[extract method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method)" refactoring. Replace your conditions to new methods.

```
if ($this->isInstructionNestingGrammar($instructionObject)){ 
   //don't change the child depth
}else if ($this->isIntructionSelect($instructionObject)){ 
   //don't change the child depth
}else{
   $insertOffset += $childDepth;
   unset($childDepth);
}
```

In new methods put every compare to separate line.

P.S. Don't be afraid of long name of methods.

Comment: I gave this a +1, but the more I think about it, the more I realize that this is just moving the bloated `if` condition to another part of the file. It looks nice, but now a programmer from the future has to locate the function declaration to find out what's happening. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Just negate the conditions and skip the `if` and `else if` parts as the two initial conditions don't do anything...

```
if (
     !($instructionObject->instruction=='nesting_grammar' && 
       $instructionObject->match=='>') 
    || !($instructionObject->instruction=='selector' 
        && is_object($this->instructions[$key+1]) 
        && $this->instructions[$key+1]->instruction == 'nesting_grammar' 
        && $this->instructions[$key+1]->match == '>')
 ) {
   $insertOffset += $childDepth;
   unset($childDepth);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, but what about something like:

```
if (my_check($instructionObject) || $instructionObject->instruction=='selector' && my_check($this->instructions[$key+1])) {
} else {
   $insertOffset += $childDepth;
   unset($childDepth);
}

function my_check($obj) {
    return is_object($obj) && $obj->instruction == 'nesting_grammar' && $obj->match == '>';
}
```

-- you are basically doing the same thing twice, time to think about a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if i'm going to span the check across multiple lines i lay it out similar to how i'd lay out a JavaScript object;

```
if (
    great big long check line goes in here &&
    another really long ugly check line goes in here too
) {
   // Do this code
}
else if (
    check 3 &&
    check 4
) {
    //Do this code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull out sub-expressions into variables. Pseudo-example:

```
flibjit = FlibjitManager.FlibjitInstance(this);
isFrob = 
    (flibjit.Froblocity >= FlibjitManager.FrobThreshold) &&   
    (flibjit.Type == FlibjitTypes.Frobby);

if (isFrob) {
   // ...
```

Comment: I like your approach with the suggested variable names! :)